# Installing / Setting up MongoDB on Mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, mean-stack

I am following this [tutorial](https://ademirgabardo.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/installing-and-running-mongodb-on-mac-osx-for-beginners/) in hopes of installing/ setting up Mongodb on my mac. When attempting to run mongodb with command 'mongod' I receive the following error "shutting down with code:100". Through research I have found that this error message is thrown because [mongodb cannot find the folder to store the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100), but isn't that what I did with command 'sudo mkdir -p /data/db' ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the data folder, when you launch `mongod`. For example:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db
```

If launching automatically, it reads from the configuration file parameter `storage.dbPath`.

Given that the default database path is `/data/db`, if `mongod` can't find that path, it could be a permissions issue, where the `mongod` process isn't the owner of the folder.