# Changing the location of mongo db in mac

Tags: database, mongodb, bash, macos

So I tried to change the location of the '**default**' location of monogo's database `/data/db` with this command in bash `$ sudo mongo --dbpath /usr/local/<new folder>` and it started right up, however after shutting down and trying start again I run `$ mongod` from bash it gives this error `"I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100"`.

1. My question is, do I have to type this `--dbpath <directory>` flag each time I want to use the database...?
2. How do I let mongo know the '**default**' directory is moved?

Answer (score 3):

So with and exhaustive searching and pouring through the documentation, I tried a lot of solutions and here is one I found that worked for me. 'This is a macOS solution'. **Note:** Rename '/what/ever/location' to your actual location, but I recommend keeping the data, db, bin, log.

When installing mongodb using homebrew (pre-requisites, install xcode).

$ `brew install mongodb`

The official documentation says it does not create a config file, so you have to create one and put in this location.

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

Once created use your text editor( of choice) to insert this code. Mine is simplified, but mongo documentation has a complete list of what else to include. [Mongo documentation storage options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage-options): **Note:** this code is written in .yaml or .yml so no tabs.

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "/what/ever/location/log/mongod.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "/what/ever/location/data/db"
  indexBuildRetry: true
  repairPath: "/what/ever/location/data/db/repairdb"
  journal:
    enabled: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
setParameter:
  enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

I put in some extra stuff like log and repair path it's your choice. Next alter your `.bash_profile` with this line:

```
# MongoDB Aliases
alias mongod="mongod --dbpath /what/ever/location/bin"
```

While you there if you haven't done so update your environment variable $PATH where the mongod shell is located.

```
export PATH="/what/ever/location/bin:$PATH"
```

In your cli (of choice) run this line to check if worked:

$ `mongod`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your installation your mongod should have a mongod.conf file the specifies your default location --dbpath does not modify the config file. You will likely need to adjust permissions on the new db directory as well.

With out seeing the error codes I would recommend the following posts:

[Changing Mongo Data Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961145/changing-mongodb-data-store-directory)

[MongoDB Error Code 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100)

Comment: I have read most of the posts and comments however I am not able to change the **'default'** location of the database. Referring to this article on the mongodb website, [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/]. they do not mention how to change this behavior. so I'm still in need of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Include an alias in your bash profile with the right dbpath.

1. Edit this file:  /Users/YOUR_NAME/.bash_profile
2. add this line to the file: 
   alias mongod="mongod --dbpath /usr/local/NEW_FOLDER"
3. Save it.
4. open a new terminal and start mongo typing: 
   mongod