# Will `sudo service mongodb start` deletes my previous data?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am working on EC2 aws. My mongo suddenly stopped connecting.

`sudo service mongodb status` displays the following:-

```
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented >database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-03-29 18:31:08 UTC; 1h 18min ago
 Main PID: 3773 (code=exited, status=100)

Mar 29 18:31:07 ip-172-31-41-39 systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Mar 29 18:31:08 ip-172-31-41-39 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Mar 29 18:31:08 ip-172-31-41-39 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I read that doing `sudo service mongodb start` might solve your problem but I fear will it **delete** my data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb shuts down with Code 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100)

Answer (score 0):

An exit code 100 for the mongodb service means that it [could not access or find the data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420544/2766650). If your data directory is protected by sudo then starting the service with sudo will solve your problem.