# MongoDB Connection Error While Connect to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As i'm new to api creation in nodejs and i tried to connect mongo db throung nodejs code and i have advance version of mongodb(V4) and nodejs(v10) and i could not able to connect please can any one help me.

my mongodb node code:

```
// Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
});
```

and cmd:
commend for db connection in cmd prompt is mongod -- for connection establishement.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 27017 } 'errrrrrrrrrrrrr'

Comment: can you access via command line: `mongo` ?

Comment: try `MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", {native_parser:true}, function(err, db) {`

Comment: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2019-05-02T14:22:30.061+0530 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2019-05-02T14:22:30.062+0530 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed @1556089774

Comment: i tired but its getting error (node:19032) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.@Vikash Singh

Comment: for windows `mongod.exe` https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb-community-edition

Comment: i tried with mongod.exe but it does not run for long time it exit with 2019-05-02T14:28:16.278+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-05-02T14:28:16.278+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100

Comment: Thanks alot its working @1556089774

Comment: you could upvote the answer in the link if it helped. :)