# Should mongodb shell be available anywhere in FS? (WSL)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just started learning mongo and having trouble with its configiration, it all seems a bit confusing.

Since started learning Node I am running WSL with Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic through Hyper with ZSH. I have tried to install mongodb thorugh NPM with no luck. As mongo is not supported in WSL I followed instalation steps from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203689/cannot-start-mongodb-on-wsl) tread and it worked.

However I am not sure if its working correctly as I can access mongod service from any directory without need to install any dependency with NPM, is it correct behaviour? Shouldn't this be a separate instance of the database?

I tried in the my prod directory:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath=/data
```

and..

```
sudo mongod --dbpath ~/mnt/c/rob/dev/code/mongodb-data
```

.. but its failing and aborting whole process with code:100.

I apologise if that is a silly question, but I am just getting more and more confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb shuts down with Code 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongod` is the server process. It basically implements the actual database.

If you want to run a local database server, you'd run `mongod`.

`mongo` is a client process. It connects to the database and allows you to issue queries, etc.

If you want to connect to a server *using the MongoDB shell*, you'd use `mongo`. The server could be on your computer or elsewhere (e.g. Atlas). It is possible to use `mongo` without `mongod`.

`mongo` has nothing to do with `npm`. It is a standalone program.