# Mongodb stopped suddenly

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am running `Mongodb` on my server and it has stopped suddenly with error code 100 and this is the errors i got it
[image]

Comment: show /data/db and it was run on docker or host?

Comment: MongoDB needs a folder to store the database. Create a data/db folder, might be there is no permission

Comment: You can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100

Comment: it run on server @Daniel

Comment: @PramodKharade if this will west the old data stored if i created this new folder

Comment: Please, check permission of existing folders

Comment: Do you have any backup? Did you upgraded you mongo? If yes, I recommend to downgrade, do backup, upgrade and recover backup.