# mongod command giving error exit code 100

Tags: mongodb

I don't remember the process I followed while installing mongodb and probably messed things up. Now everything works fine if the mongoDB server as a service is running but when it is not running and I execute mongod command it gives me error. I have added it to path variable so that is not the problem.

```
C:\Users\HP>mongod
```

{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:48.941+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.497+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.498+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.501+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.515+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.517+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.517+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.528+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":18568,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"LAPTOP-HV3CI0DL"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.529+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.529+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.0","gitVersion":"1184f004a99660de6f5e745573419bda8a28c0e9","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.530+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19043)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.542+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.549+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.549+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.551+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.561+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.561+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.562+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.574+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.574+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.575+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.576+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.577+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.578+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.582+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.590+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.591+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.592+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.592+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.593+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.593+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-01-29T21:42:49.599+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}

C:\Users\HP>

Can someone help?

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420466/mongodb-shuts-down-with-code-100

Comment: That directory not found message should be a huge clue.

Comment: @R2D2 I tried it but it didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: there is alot of hints in above link , you may add to the question what you have attempted , in general the error message say you dont have write access to the data folder ... , but it could be that you did not provide correct config file to your mongod executable ...

Answer (score 4):

You should define the folder for DB data and logging after creating them:

```
mkdir "C:\Users\HP\data"
mkdir "C:\Users\HP\log"
mongod --dbpath "C:\Users\HP\data" --logpath "C:\Users\HP\log\mongod.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a "data" folder inside the C: drive
Inside "data" create another folder as "db"
Make sure you have the same case.

Answer (score 0):

Open the command prompt as an administrator and then run the command

```
  C:\Users\HP>mongosh
```

Don't forget to install Mongodb shell from its website

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have a proper answer if you are working in Windows
use following commands

> `cd c:/`

> `mkdir data/db`

and then use `mongod` command